# My Ethereum contract is not receiving parameters from a Javascript call

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I'm sending a transaction to a contract from Javascript through web3. The transaction is created. The solidity function is (partially) executed because it sends the token it's expected to send... but, values are no stored in a mapping.

I tested with browser-solidity and it works. I tested with https://www.myetherwallet.com and it works. In both cases, I can retrieve the values of the mapping. But when I do through javascript, it doesn't work.

Here is the code of javascript calling function:

```
  scheduleAppointment : function(_patient, _doctor, _appointmentDateTime) {
    var patientAddress      = document.getElementById("patientInput");
    var doctorAddress       = document.getElementById("doctorInput");
    var appointmentDateTime = document.getElementById("timeStampInput");
    contractInstance.scheduleAppointment.sendTransaction(patientAddress.value,
                                                         doctorAddress.value,
                                                         appointmentDateTime.value,
                                                         {gas:140000, from:web3.eth.accounts[0]});
  }
```

Here is the code of solidity function (this function does not send tokens, only stores to mapping):

```
function scheduleAppointment(address _patient, address _doctor, uint _appointmentDateTime) {
    appointmentsList[_patient][_doctor][_appointmentDateTime].appointmentStatus    = 1;
}
```

As you see, it would be impossible to make it more simple.. but it doesn't work. Transaction is created, but the value is not stored in the mapping.

Should I convert parameters before sending them from javascript? I couldn't find any reference for sending many parameters with `sendTransaction`. I've tried converting the integer value with `parseInt` when calling the function with javascript, but it's the same.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, the functions worked properly. 
The problem was that they run out of gas...
I can remove the question if you consider that it does not add anything useful.

Comment: It can be helpful to others, missing the correct gas value is a pretty common issue.